# How to know the android language from a JAR lib

Tags: java, android, localization, jar

I am writing a JAR library that will be used on desktop and also on android.
The JAR is localized, therefore I would like to know the current android language in order to set the locale accordingly.

How should I do that?

UPDATE: The locale is the same of the android language, but ResourceBundle.getString() always revert to the default locale.

LAST UPDATE: It's a bug on Android, if my locale is it_IT it looks exclusively for Locale_it_IT; and skips Locale_it (which instead is accepted on Java).

OOPS! it ACTUALLY was a bug on my code... android is case sensitive and I created a resourcebundle with locale IT instead of it... shame on me.

Comment: I thought android compiled to a different bytecode format than normal java class files (which are normally what a .jar file contins).  Now I'm going to have to go look up how all this works.

Comment: @Bill the packaging process rewrites 'normal' jars/classes into the Android bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android supporrs the normal java Locale related methods, so you should be fine by just asking for `Locale.getDefault()`

Comment: When writing the post, I had no IDE or javadoc at hand :) And you did not write how you set the locale - if you already check for the locale you should be fine.